# Copying and Appending to an empty list

Tags: python, python-3.x

In a piece of code I need to copy a list and append a new value. I have found the following behaviour:

```
a=[]
b=[n for n in a].append('val')
print(b)
None
```

While, the following works as I require:

```
b=[n for n in a]
b.append('val')
print(b)
['val']
```

Any insight why it is so?

Comment: `[n for n in a]` is the most complicated way to copy a list. What's wrong with `a[:]` or `list(a)` or `copy.copy(a)`? When people see a list comprehension, they're going to think you were trying to actually do something to the elements (or filter some of them out) and have to spend time convincing themselves that you really weren't trying to do anything before they can read your code. If you just write `b = a[:]`, anyone will know what that means instantly just by skimming.

Comment: Also, why do you want to make a copy and then append, instead of just using the `+` operator, that does that all in one go, and more readably (and usable within an expression, which you seem to want).

Answer (score 4):

`append` modifies the list *in place*, it doesn't return a new list, that's why you're getting `None`.

See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#built-in-types):

> .. The methods that add, subtract, or rearrange their members in place, and don’t return a specific item, *never return the collection instance itself but None*.

Answer (score 2):

Method `append` returns `None`, because it modifies list in place, that is why `b` in your first example is `None`. You could use list concatenation in order to copy a list and append an element to it:

```
In [238]: a = [1, 2, 3]

In [239]: b = a + [4]

In [240]: b
Out[240]: [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because `b=[n for n in a].append('val')` does not return anything. In specific `append('val')` does not return any value.